# why does a JKS load work even when we supply null password?

Tags: java, security, ssl, keystore, jks

I have a `JKS` file which was generated using a password. I have a java code that uses that `keystore` to connect to a url. Now when I load the keystore, I had mistakenly passed the *password* as `null`. But to my amazement, the connection still went through.

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
store.load(stream, null);
```

This kind of behavior looked suspicious to me. Is there an explanation for this?

**EDIT:**

If this behavior is as expected, then why is the passphrase required when creating a keystore via keytool?

Comment: Do you indeed connect to a `https` site (to rule out the password only being used when actually needed)?

Comment: Yes, I connect to a `HTTPS` site!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't supply the password:

1. The keystore isn't integrity-checked on opening.
2. You can't access any private-key entries.

For a `KeyStore` used as a *truststore*, i.e. containing only trusted certificates, this is a normal usage.

> If this behavior is as expected, then why is the passphrase required when creating a keystore via keytool?

So that you can supply one on opening, so as to get the behaviour at (1) or (2) above.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the second point? how do you add a private key in the keystore? Also, what is normal usage when using it as trustStore? is it with password or without password?

Comment: You add a private key to the keystore via the API or the `keytool`. It is normal usage for a truststore not to supply a password, which is what your question is about. I don't understand why you're asking either of these questions.

Answer (score -1):

Hm, I think that the passphrase you're passing is to ensure integrity of the keystore itself (upon changing the contents itself). However, if no passphrase provided, the contents (keys/certificates) can still be read - which is what you're experiencing.

For illustration purposes, you can also view contents of a keystore by running the command:`keytool -list -keystore <keystore>` - which does not imply passing a passphrase to the keystore itself.

You can also read more about this related to the load()-function itself on the KeyStore-object here: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load(java.io.InputStream,%20char[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load(java.io.InputStream,%20char%5B%5D)).

> stream - the input stream from which the keystore is loaded, or null
>
> password - the password used to check the integrity of the keystore, the password used to unlock the keystore, or null